# Android - Login and Sharing with Google Plus

Tags: android, google-plus, logout, sharing

I want my app to login and share with Google Plus Login, first time it pops up and asking from which Google account you want to login and share,but when I tried to share at the second time the pop up is not working and it is taking default account from which I have posted earlier.

I have tried to clear the default account but still not working.
Will any one please suggest me some solution?

Comment: Show some code..see this link https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/

Comment: I have already refer to this link the sharing part is working fine I am able to share the content but the problem is when I try to share at the second time the pop is not working(it is not asking from which account you want to share) and it takes the default account from which I have posted earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SHARE = 1000;
    private PlusClient mPlusClient;
    private PlusClient.Builder mPlusClientBuilder;
    private PlusShare.Builder mPlusShareBuilder;

//Inside onCreate()

mPlusClientBuilder = new Builder(this, this, this);
        mPlusClientBuilder.setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN, Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE);
        mPlusClient = mPlusClientBuilder.build();
mPlusClient.connect();

//on click on button share or login

btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (!mPlusClient.isConnected() && btnSignIn.getText().equals(getString(R.string.signin))) {
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                } else if (mPlusClient.isConnected() && btnSignIn.getText().equals(getString(R.string.signout))) {
                    mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();
                    mPlusClient.disconnect();




                }
            }
        });

//Overrides methods

@Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (result.hasResolution()) {
            // The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
            // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
            // connection dialog.
            try {
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mPlusClient.disconnect();
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();

    }

//onActivity result:

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mPlusClient.disconnect();
            mPlusClient.connect();
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SHARE && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            finish();
        }

    }

//on Button Share click event:

btnShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) {

                    mPlusShareBuilder = new PlusShare.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    mPlusShareBuilder.setType("text/plain");
                    mPlusShareBuilder.setText(IN_SHARE_MESSAGE + IN_SHARE_LINK);
                    mPlusShareBuilder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse(IN_SHARE_LINK));

                    // Intent shareIntent =
                    // PlusShare.Builder.from(IJoomerGooglePlusShareActivity.this).setText().setType("text/plain").setContent(Uri.parse("http://example.com/cheesecake/lemon"))
                    // .getIntent();
                    Intent shareIntent = mPlusShareBuilder.getIntent();
                    startActivityForResult(shareIntent, REQUEST_CODE_SHARE);
                } else {
                    Yoast.makeText(YOUR ACTIVITY.this,getString(R.string.signin_with_google_account), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: not working still I am facing the same problem the pop up is not working at the second time and it takes the default account from which I have posted earlier

Comment: ya it will, because if you need each and everytime asked, then when you come out of the app, just logout the previous session. Then only it will show new dialog everytime.